# Environment variable explicitly set on /etc/profile is lost on Arch

Tags: linux, arch-linux, environment-variables, path, profile

This was my `/etc/profile` before I modified it.

```
$ cat /etc/profile
# /etc/profile

# Append "$1" to $PATH when not already in.
# This function API is accessible to scripts in /etc/profile.d
append_path () {
    case ":$PATH:" in
        *:"$1":*)
            ;;
        *)
            PATH="${PATH:+$PATH:}$1"
    esac
}

# Append our default paths
append_path '/usr/local/sbin'
append_path '/usr/local/bin'
append_path '/usr/bin'

# Force PATH to be environment
export PATH

# Load profiles from /etc/profile.d
if test -d /etc/profile.d/; then
    for profile in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
        test -r "$profile" && . "$profile"
    done
    unset profile
fi

# Unload our profile API functions
unset -f append_path

# Source global bash config, when interactive but not posix or sh mode
if test "$BASH" &&\
   test "$PS1" &&\
   test -z "$POSIXLY_CORRECT" &&\
   test "${0#-}" != sh &&\
   test -r /etc/bash.bashrc
then
    . /etc/bash.bashrc
fi

# Termcap is outdated, old, and crusty, kill it.
unset TERMCAP

# Man is much better than us at figuring this out
unset MANPATH
```

And these were the `PATH`, `MANPATH` and `INFOPATH` respectively:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/home/a/.dotnet/tools:/var/lib/flatpak/exports/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl
```

```
$ echo $MANPATH
```

```
$ echo $INFOPATH
```

After installing TeX Live, I edited `/etc/profile` so that programs would be able to locate the files.

```
$ cat /etc/profile
# /etc/profile

# Append "$1" to $PATH when not already in.
# This function API is accessible to scripts in /etc/profile.d
append_path () {
    case ":$PATH:" in
        *:"$1":*)
            ;;
        *)
            PATH="${PATH:+$PATH:}$1"
    esac
}

# Append our default paths
append_path '/usr/local/sbin'
append_path '/usr/local/bin'
append_path '/usr/bin'
append_path '/usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux'

# Force PATH to be environment
export PATH
export MANPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/doc/man:$MANPATH
export INFOMATH=/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/doc/info:$INFOPATH

# Load profiles from /etc/profile.d
if test -d /etc/profile.d/; then
    for profile in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
        test -r "$profile" && . "$profile"
    done
    unset profile
fi

# Unload our profile API functions
unset -f append_path

# Source global bash config, when interactive but not posix or sh mode
if test "$BASH" &&\
   test "$PS1" &&\
   test -z "$POSIXLY_CORRECT" &&\
   test "${0#-}" != sh &&\
   test -r /etc/bash.bashrc
then
    . /etc/bash.bashrc
fi

# Termcap is outdated, old, and crusty, kill it.
unset TERMCAP

# Man is much better than us at figuring this out
# unset MANPATH
```

I added `append_path '/usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux'`, `export MANPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/doc/man:$MANPATH` and `export INFOMATH=/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/doc/info:$INFOPATH`. I also commented out `unset MANPATH`. After a `reboot` here is how the three environment variables look like.

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux:/home/a/.dotnet/tools:/var/lib/flatpak/exports/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl
```

```
$ echo $MANPATH
/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/doc/man:
```

```
$ echo $INFOPATH
```

`PATH` and `MANPATH` were changed to the desired values but `INFOPATH` is still empty. Why is this happening?